# Fscanf: Reading Digits seperatly in Groups of 4

Tags: c, hex, scanf

I have a file with Hex Data encoded in Blocks of 4 Digits.

```
400F
4101
6010
1000
```

I want to read each Digit seperatly in Blocks of 4.
Like: Read 400F and save them in Seperate unsigned shorts.
I could only do it with having the Digits seperated by Spaces:

```
uint16_t test[4];    
fscanf(file, "%hx%hx%hx%hx", &test[0], &test[1], &test[2], &test[3])
```

It should look like this:

```
test[0] -> 4
test[1] -> 0
test[2] -> 0
test[3] -> 15
```

(And all this ofcourse in a Loop, to get more than one line)

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks :)

Comment: Well, I want to convert them to unsigned short. Not unsigned long. But to read them as a String first is Probably a good idea. Thanks

Comment: Use `%c%c%c%c` to read each character. Then parse it each character as a hex digit.

Comment: Sounds like you want `"%1hx%1hx%1hx%1hx"` to read each digit individually

Answer (score 0):

Read it into a 32-bit number using `%x`, then use shifting and masking to extract each digit.

```
uint32_t input;
uint16_t test[4];
fscanf(file, "%x", input);
test[0] = (input >> 24) & 0xf;
test[1] = (input >> 16) & 0xf;
test[2] = (input >> 8) & 0xf;
test[3] = input & 0xf;
```